# Safari Web Extension Fails to Send Native Message

Tags: javascript, xcode, safari-extension, safari-web-extension, safariservices

I'm trying to create a Safari Web Extension to my native app. I want to have a popup with a button which when clicked will communicate with my native app:

```
    browser.runtime.sendNativeMessage({message: "Open Main App"}, function(response) {
    console.log("Received sendNativeMessage response:");
    console.log(response);
    });
```

However, the app fails to receive the message sent from the Safari Web Extension:

```
    func beginRequest(with context: NSExtensionContext) {

    its the function that handles all things
    then
    
    if msg.contains("Open Main App") == true {
      print("NEED TO OPEN")
      guard let url = URL(string: "player:Vacation?index=1") else {
         return
      }
      NSWorkspace.shared.open(url)
    }
```

Safari log showed this error message:

```
  ReferenceError: Can't find variable: browser
```

What is wrong?

Comment: I am running into this too. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Did you use `browser.runtime.sendNativeMessage` from the background script?
You also need to set the permission in the manifest file.
Like so: `"permissions": [ "nativeMessaging" ]`